# Figure out the code

Tags: pattern, password, number-theory

So remember all those puzzles about 100 or 1000 or however many logicians abducted by aliens and they are going to be killed if they can't figure out their hat color or the number on their back? Well it turns out you were such a bright mind that the aliens abducted you, and luckily you were one of the logicians that survived.

Unfortunately, instead of taking you back home, they just left you in a room with all the other logicians that survived. Escaping doesn't seem very likely any time soon because right now everyone is focusing on getting food every day. There is a single fridge in the corner of the room but it is one of those newfangled fridges and it has a security code that you have to put in to open it. The fridge has a panel on the top that displays 5 digits, and those digits change every day, along with the fridge restocking. The problem is that when the fridge restocks, the security code changes. For the first six days, you've had to brute force the code by just typing every combination in until you get it (only 100000 combinations, not too bad), but you really need to figure out what the pattern is for the codes so you can focus on escaping instead of cheeseburgers.

The panel numbers and codes for that day are as follows:

> Panel -- Code
>   12345 = 56306
>   04418 = 35129
>   20530 = 65048
>   54472 = 68425
>   00000 = 00000
>   60454 = 95126
>   29830 = 39175
>   00000 = 03334
>   08224 = 35386
>   14412 = ?????

Today the panel says 14412. Can you figure out the code and what the algorithm is so you can get the food easily each day?

About the brute-force method: Pertaining to David James' comment,the brute force method started with 00000 on the fifth day, but it does not follow the pattern of 00001, 00002... One logician is in charge of the brute-forcing and each day he starts with the panel number, and then does what seems like a random sequence. At least that's what you all think... he's been a little bit looney since the abduction but you all let him use his "sequence" to make him happy.

Yesterday in the fridge, someone found a fortune cookie which contained the following fortune:

> Look backwards to go forward

It's probably just a generic fortune mass produced in a cookie factory, but what if it's a clue about solving the code?

Another fortune cookie has shown up:

> 651
> 930
> 862
> 565
> 000
> 696
> 532
> 400

What could those numbers be referring to?

More fortune cookies:

> 56345
> 35118
> 65030
> 68472
> 00000
> 95154
> 39130
> 03300
> 35324

And:

> Codes to a day need not connect
> But codes to the panel need be
> Look how to get panel from code
> And you'll be able to get free

Last fortune cookie:

> There can be more than one, but each can't be more than once.

**Days passed: 9** (seems like a lot more though)

*Note: Please post partial answers if you think you have anything so I can see where you are having problems*

Comment: Is the code always strictly greater than the panel number when it's greater than 00000?

Comment: I would think there are multiple patterns which would generate different codes for a panel display of 29830.  It is also possible that the panel display is irrelevant and that the code is just a sequence.

Comment: Write down the 6 codes we already know, unplug the fridge briefly every 6 days, and hopefully the sequence of codes will repeat.  Also, I suspect they were happy on day 5 if their brute force method was to start at code 00000 since they would have gotten it right on the first try that day.

Comment: I could post 100.000 answers and I would certainly get 1 right, but that will take too long I'm afraid :(

Comment: If we call panel digits *Pn* and code digits *Cn*, then this seems to hold true: *C3 = C2 - P3*... So, one digit down, 4 to go...

Comment: any hints? any advice?

Comment: 86,400 seconds in a day, so that is some super fast typing!

Comment: @rand al'thor The code does not always have to be a larger integer than the panel number, but most of the time it is. Also thanks for the edit, I knew the wording was odd but I was too tired to figure out what it was xD

Comment: @JLee there might be a reason that they are able to 'beat the odds' and find the code before the day is up.

Comment: For every day where P3 equals 4, C4 equals 2. Coincidence???

Comment: @Kevin That does happen to be a coincidence. There won't be any specific number conversions like 4->2, 3->6, etc. With the panel/codes given so far, an algorithm for solving any code could be determined.

Comment: I think, given pattern is irrelevant, and I would use hint and try codes 56306 and 39175. If 56306 is true, then for every day of week there is unique code, if 39175 is true, then you have to go forward and backward  (every odd week from 56306 to 39175, and every even week from 39175 to 56306).

Comment: You forgot to edit number of days, **Days passed : 8.**

Comment: @TahirImanov I could have sworn I changed it lol

Comment: 3rd hint please...

Comment: Each number in the second fortune cookie refers to a day in the puzzle (first day = first number, second day = second number, etc). It seems _F1_ = _C5_, _F2_ = _C1_, and _F3_ = _P1_, where _Fn_ is a digit of the corresponding number in the second fortune cookie and _Pn_ and _Cn_ are the digits of the panel and code respectively.

Comment: @JeffersonSteelflex I wonder if there's a reason for the order of C5, C1, P1

Comment: WRT the recent edit: I've actually made some progress, it's just slow going :)  -- and a partial solve doesn't really seem to be meaningful with this puzzle.

Comment: @lorimer showing a partial solve would help me figure out where you are getting stuck, but if you'd like to keep your work to yourself until it's fully solved, questions as comments would be helpful for me to figure out what hints to do.

Comment: If it makes any sense, I don't consider myself stuck; there are three elements and one pattern I still have to work with. It needs thinking time more than anything.

Comment: @lorimer Yeah I understand. Just letting you know if you get stuck on any of the parts (although from what I've given you, I believe the hardest parts have been made a little easier) feel free to let me know where it is that's causing trouble. Good luck

Comment: Hmm... why is the fortune cookie 68425 and not 68472?  (Of course these new fortune cookies are C1-C2-C3-P4-P5, following on Jefferson's observation.)

Comment: Every other one satisfies C5 = C1 + P1 -- but this is probably spurious, because an "every other one" rule is too complicated...

Comment: Where I'm at::
with
`P4,5 = C1*(C2+C3)`
and
 `C2 = P3 + C3`
and with `P4,5 = 12` and `P3 = 4` it follows that `C1,2,3` can only be either one of these 3 possibilities: `184`, `251`or `340`.
Hope it helps others.

Comment: Well at the very least it will be amazingly helpful to the guys trying to crack the code... if the goal was really just to free up some time to work on escaping then it seems we've done the job :)

Comment: :D I guess you're right! From 100000 to 300 :)

Comment: Really, I think I'm at the point where I just need to find where the chain starts. All the rest will (should) fall in at that point, but there has to be something about the iteration (weekday) that provides an initial value.

Comment: @lorimer I added a new hint to point you in the right direction

Comment: Heh, thanks, but that was the bit I already had from the first hint ;)  Somewhere the chain has to begin, is all -- right now everything i have ends up in a circular reference and I'm looking to avoid any guessing. Knowing the day doesn't matter does at least tell me where not to look though.

Again, though - don't worry on my account. I haven't had time to sit and really process it all weekend so.

Comment: There must still be some connection between each day though, because *something* has to have caused the different outputs from 00000. Unless you do just have to do a series of educated guesses each day (maybe the looney brute forcer knows this already and is doing exactly that), but that would make for a pretty unsatisfying puzzle...

Comment: @Alconja Lookat what everyone has already solved to find out why there are two separate codes for 00000

Comment: @MisterEman22 - I understand all the hints given and can see what they're doing, which means on any given day I can reduce the number of codes you have to try to a manageable number. But given the nature of the formulas, there's multiple possible valid outcomes for some digits. So *either* there's some connection between daily  codes, which produce the different outputs for the same input, *or* the best you can do is reduce the possibilities to a smaller subset of guesses. Sounds like you're implying the latter, which I'm saying isn't a very satisfying result as a puzzle solver.

Comment: @Alconja I guess I didn't think this through when creating the puzzle and reusing 00000. I'm assuming you have the answer right now but I didn't give you guys enough to really fully understand what I was implying as an answer. I'll make another hint that should make it clearer.

Comment: @MisterEman22 - too be clear, it's still a good puzzle, it's just that undisclosed ambiguity is frustrating because you waste time looking for something that isn't there. You just needed to either tweak your equations to ensure a single provably correct code each day (and that could include using previous day's codes/panel values as inputs to create different outputs for seemingly identical panel inputs), or alternatively reword the puzzle to ask "how can they reduce their brute-forcing" rather than "what's the code" (the former would make a better puzzle, but would be tougher to construct).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to determine exactly the code to enter on any given day, but we can narrow it down a great deal as follows:

First, let's define the digits of the *Panel* as being *Pn* and the digits of the *Code* as being *Cn*. Now, there are various mathematical relationships that can be applied, to relate digits of the code to digits of the panel:

- $C2 - C3 = P3$
- $C5 \mod C1 = P1$
- $C1(C2 + C3) = P4,P5$
- $C1 - C3 + C4 = P2$

Thus we have a set of equations, which collectively cover all the digits of the code. However, because there's ambiguity (eg. with the mod operator), we still can't directly determine any given code.

Taking the latest panel value of $14412$, we know the following:

- $C2 - C3 = 4$
- $C5 \mod C1 = 1$
- $C1(C2 + C3) = 12$
- $C1 - C3 + C4 = 4$

(I'm sure an actual mathematician would do a cleaner job of this part of the logic, but I'll fumble along). We can rework these equations to give us, $C1(4 + 2C3) = 12$ (combining equation 1 & 3), or $C1 = \frac{12}{(4 + 2C3)}$.

Given that $C1$ must be a whole number, then $C3$ must be $0$, $1$, $4$, making $C1$ equal to $3$, $2$, or $1$. However, we also need the remainder when dividing $C5$ by $C1$ to be $1$ (noting that there's precedent in the examples for treating *x%0 as 0*), which means $C1\ne1$.

Re-entering these possible values in the third equation to get $C2$, we have our code as either $251??$ or $340??$. Then using the 4th equation to get $C4$, we arrive at $2513?$ or $3401?$. Finally, using the 2nd equation we get a $C5$ value of $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$ (for the first possible code) and $1$, $4$, $7$ (for the second).

Thus, **today's code** is one of the following:

- $25131$
- $25133$
- $25135$
- $25137$
- $25139$
- $34011$
- $34014$
- $34017$

So, not perfect, but certainly faster than brute forcing $100,000$ combinations...

Comment: What I was hinting at with the last fortune cookie as well as earlier is that there are multiple codes per day that work, but each only works once for a given panel code (sort of a backwards conversion). When 00000 repeats, the first code can't be used again. Originally I was just trying to find a way of fitting it into the story that there were multiple codes for a panel. Nice job though.

Comment: @Mistereman22 - it should be the first hint